# formatting multiple city names into universal name for each city all at once using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

change all city name into one universal name.

```
        City    b   c
0   New york    1   1
1   New York    2   2
2   N.Y.        3   3
3   NY          4   4
```

They call refer to the city New york however python sees them as separate entity therefore I've changed all into one.

```
df["City"] = df["City"].replace({"N.Y.":"New york", "New York": "New york", "NY": "New york"})
```

After this I need to check if all variation of new york is covered, to do that I've created a function

```
def universal_ok(universal_name):
    count = 0
    for c in df.City:
        if c == universal_name:
            count += 1

    # This only works when column consists of only one type of city
    if count == len(df.City):
        return "Yes all names are formatted correctly"
    else:
        return f"there are {len(df.City) - count} names that need to be changed"

universal_ok("New york")
```

but the problem is what about when there are more than one city in a column

```
    City        b   c
0   New york    1   1
1   New York    2   2
2   N.Y.        3   3
3   NY          4   4
4   Toronto     3   2
5   TO          3   2
6   toronto     3   2
```

is there a way to change each city to universal name?

Comment: I don't think this task is _really_ about `pandas`. You first need to build some dicts of mapping abbreviations and any sorts of short names to proper name. Besides, what is the _universal name_ after all? N.Y can also stand for [North Yorkshire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Yorkshire) but pandas (or computer to be more general) will never be able to tell the difference without any instruction :(

Answer (score 1):

### Convert to Lower, Unique Values, Map and Count:

### Data:

```py
     City  b  c
 New york  1  1
 New York  2  2
     N.Y.  3  3
       NY  4  4
  Toronto  3  2
       TO  3  2
  toronto  3  2
```

#### Convert to Lower:

- This will reduce the variations of the city names.
- [`pandas.Series.str.lower`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lower.html)

```py
df.City = df.City.str.lower()

     City  b  c
 new york  1  1
 new york  2  2
     n.y.  3  3
       ny  4  4
  toronto  3  2
       to  3  2
  toronto  3  2
```

#### Unique Values:

- This will give you all the values in the column
- [`pandas.Series.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html)

```py
df.City.unique()

array(['new york', 'n.y.', 'ny', 'toronto', 'to'], dtype=object)
```

#### Mapping the City Names:

- Use the unique values list, to map the values to the preferred form
- I created a tuple, then used dict comprehension to create the dictionary

  - I did this, so I wouldn't have to repeatedly type the preferred city name, because I'm lazy / efficient, that way.
- [Tuples](https://realpython.com/python-lists-tuples/#python-tuples)
- [Python Dictionary Comprehension Tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-dictionary-comprehension)
- [`pandas.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

```py
cities_tup = (('New York', ['ny', 'n.y.', 'new york']),
              ('Toronto', ['toronto', 'to']))

cities_map = {y:x[0] for x in cities_tup for y in x[1]}

{'ny': 'New York',
 'n.y.': 'New York',
 'new york': 'New York',
 'toronto': 'Toronto',
 'to': 'Toronto'}

df.City = df.City.map(cities_map)

     City  b  c
 New York  1  1
 New York  2  2
 New York  3  3
 New York  4  4
  Toronto  3  2
  Toronto  3  2
  Toronto  3  2
```

#### Unique Counts to verify:

- Verify city names have been updated and count them
- [`pandas.Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)

```py
df.City.value_counts()

New York    4
Toronto     3
Name: City, dtype: int64
```

### Remarks

- Undoubtedly, there are alternate methods to accomplish this task, but I think this is straightforward and easy to follow.

  - Someone will probably come along and offer a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

You need a specific column with some sort of city id, otherwise you won’t be able to distinguish between Paris, France and Paris, Texas, nor will you be able to group Istanbul and Constantinople.